# Problems with html select + firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I'm trying to do on "component" where i have radio, and select and some other info on a div.

And anywhere you click on div you select the radio, this is the expected behavior.

But, i can't do the select works, because always when I click on select to get the dropbox value, it open and close. This happens just on firefox.

I'm on firefox 20.0.1.

I can't take the select out of div, this is the obvious solution, anyone have any other idea how i can fix this?

Take a look

http://jsbin.com/ikixuw/1/edit

Comment: I see it's ok with chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your select outside label, like this:

```
<div class="box-pedido-frm-pagamentos">
<label class="label-frm-pagamentos" title="Total: R$ 314,00">
<input id="ca_dinners_C" class="radio-frm-pagamentos" type="radio" value="cartao_dinners_C" valor="314.00" name="escolhapgt">
</label>
<select class="input-small select-frm-pagamentos">
<option value="1|314.00|314,00"> 1x R$ 314,00 </option>
<option value="2|157.00|157,00"> 2x R$ 157,00 </option>
<option value="3|104.66|104,66"> 3x R$ 104,66 </option>
<option value="4|78.50|78,50"> 4x R$ 78,50 </option>
<option value="5|62.80|62,80"> 5x R$ 62,80 </option>
<option value="6|52.33|52,33"> 6x R$ 52,33 </option>
<option value="7|44.85|44,85"> 7x R$ 44,85 </option>
<option value="8|39.25|39,25"> 8x R$ 39,25 </option>
<option value="9|34.88|34,88"> 9x R$ 34,88 </option>
<option value="10|31.40|31,40"> 10x R$ 31,40 </option>
<option value="11|28.54|28,54"> 11x R$ 28,54 </option>
<option value="12|26.16|26,16"> 12x R$ 26,16 </option>
</select>
<span class="total-frm-pagamentos">Total: R$ 314,00</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Select is inside Label. Remove it from label, but keep in div.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Firefox. They don't seem to care, since this has been around since pre-HTML 2.0

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=option-label